# WPF: PART_ContentHost not scrolling

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, scrollviewer

I am trying to make a Log area within my application and the customer has requested the ability to cut/paste the log messages from this area.

I originally was using the following to setup the log area with scrolling, but this does not allow the user to select & copy text:

```
<ScrollViewer DataContext="{StaticResource Log}"
              Content="{Binding Appender.Notification}"
              Height="150">
    <ScrollViewer.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        </Style>                    
    </ScrollViewer.Resources>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I found [this solution](http://compilewith.net/2013/02/wpf-read-only-selectable-text.html) to create a read only TextBox with select-able text:

```
    <TextBox Name="LoggingTextBox"
             Height="250"
             Width="950"
             DataContext="{StaticResource Log}"
             Text="{Binding Appender.Notification}"
             HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
             VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
```

This works to allow the selection of text within the log area but the scrolling does not work.  I added the properties for *ScrollBarVisibility (not in the original solution).

How can I get the scrolling to work using this TextBox styling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is pretty simple: just change your `Border` to a `ScrollViewer`, and you will get the standard scrolling behavior for a `TextBox`.